# RelativeLayout fills parent when wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout that is set to wrap_content for the height. However it keeps filling the whole layout. If I set the height to a set amount for example 200dp, it works well but I need it to be wrap_content as the child layouts will change in height.

So my question is how do I get the Relative layout to actually wrap content.

Thanks
Adrian

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundlayout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/row_selector1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </RadioGroup>



    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"></TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/numAndDen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/numerator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/denominator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowmult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/multiply"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <EditText

            android:id="@+id/multiplier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/row_selector2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: because your child views in RelativeLayout has match_parent height and second check RelativeLayout  background that also affect here, replace all child height also to wrap_content

Comment: Thanks for answering. The reason I did that was because I wanted each child to end up with the same height. Is there anyway around this issue without using match_parent